# Loading ros_control_gazebo_plugin - Gazebo version 1.9.5

Tags: control, gazebo, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a problem with use the `ros_control`: [No type element found for transmission](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6057425). See my [urdf](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6057478). For get control functional what I need?

I am using [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo), as well as [this one](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_demos).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3718/loading-ros_control_gazebo_plugin---gazebo-version-1.9.5/) by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Eduardo,

I'm afraid you tried to follow the ros_control tutorial that was not ready to be used yet (as noted at top of page). There have been lots of changes with ros_control since I made that initial draft. I just over-hauled the [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo) and now I'd say it is much closer to being production ready (90%).

In particular, the [format of transmissions](http://ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/Transmission) that you have attempted to use has changed, be sure to update your URDF transmissions.

---

Originally posted by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) with karma: 369 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-07-24**:
Very good Dave, your tip worked, but I'm still having a problem, [WARN] [WallTime: 1374687405.894700] [48.796000] Controller Spawner couldn't reach controller_manager to load controllers. My yaml:(https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6072791) and my launch: (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6072802)

**Comment by [Cdrwolfe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/454/cdrwolfe/) on 2013-08-01**:
Same here seems to hang on load controller

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2013-08-14**:
I think this is a namespace error...
you might could try to change your namespace to ns="/"
This worked for me...